# How to link to images when using CSS3 inline

Tags: django, html, css

I'm using CSS3 inline in the html, and since images seem to be referenced by the css stylesheet location, how can I link to images without one?

When I do this:

```
      <input type="image" name='voteup' value="Up" src="/index/images/ArrowUp.PNG"/>
```

It gives me a broken link of this value:

http://*localhost*/index/images/ArrowUp.PNG

and this:

```
.myButtonDown {
    background:url('images/ArrowDown.PNG') no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    border: none;
}

.....

<input type="submit" name='votedown2' value="Down2" class="myButtonDown"/>
```

Is just blank....

Comment: what is the correct url of your image? Is it `http://localhost/index/images/ArrowUp.png` or something else?

Comment: I'm using django, so its in django/mysite/... etc., but I don't see how that relates to /localhost/index/...

Answer (score 0):

Use this and put your image in images folder.

```
.myButtonDown {
    background: url( 'images/ArrowDown.PNG' ) no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 36px;
    width: 36px;
}

<input type="submit" name='votedown2' value="Down2" class="myButtonDown"/>
```

Comment: I'm really missing the point here, none of my urls work, does the image have to be hosted?